# When making responsive components, at what point do you break it into two components?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I realize there’s no one answer to this question, and as always, ‘it depends’. All discussion is welcome, and professional, experience-based input it appreciated!

At what point do you break a component into two components — one for mobile ish sizes, and one for desktop ish sizes, VS having a lot of complex CSS and ‘conditional’ HTML in one component?

I was just making a navbar for a website (exciting!) and the desktop navbar is extremely simple. It can be a dumb functional component. The mobile navbar adds some HTML and child components, resizes, reformats, needs an open/closed state, etc.

For the sake of debugging and maintainability, it seems like mobile is adding too much complexity to the desktop version, and the desktop version doesn’t seem to make sense among the mobile code. It’s just a lot of CSS and HTML in the same file that becomes a little less straightforward with two very different behaviors distracting each other.

But for the sake of performance, components mounting, etc. it would be a sacrifice to break this up into a container header with the two children and add additional work for React.

I'm curious, in your experience, have you encountered this problem before? How have you decided to solve it? Why? At what point do you break it up? Do you prefer the clarity of granular components, or the clarity of having all the CSS and HTML in one spot? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you are using React you can easily check if it's mobile or larger then mobile and include either one you require and if you need to have multiple navigations it's better to mount just the one you need.

But again I wonder how come you are adding that many things/items to your navigation on mobile but on desktop you are keeping it so simple?
Isn't the point of navigation that you have everything accessible with one or two clicks?

If such a complex navigation is required on mobile it only makes sense that a bit more complex navigation could be required on desktop as well :)

Don't get me wrong I have been in the same place as you are right now but it all comes back to what do you want your customers to click on? 
If the conversion happens on few links only there's no need for a huge complex mobile navigation, just make sure user can access everything they might require.

After all you can easily create a search form that would be able to help you with reducing data required in the navigation on mobile.

Not saying that I love huge navigations on desktop but if it's necessary on mobile I have a feeling it might be on desktop as well.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! All good points. I may have made my mobile nav sound more complicated than it actually is. It's pretty basic, but compared to literally no logic for the desktop version, you could call it complex. The information architecture, styles, flow etc are consistent and consider what I want users to click. (But thanks for bringing it up!)

You said that in React I can easily check if the screen is mobile or not. I'm pretty new to React so I'm wondering, are you referring to using Javascript's window object, or does React provide something I'm not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: Np, it's just that sometimes we like to overthink some components even tho they should as simple as possible :) As for the screen size you could do both - either use window object or use cerebral JS or use http://featurejs.com/ depends on how much info do you need. If you only require screen size there's no need to include any extra library. e.g. this is what you can get from cerebral http://cerebraljs.com/docs/addons/useragent.html you get JS media queries and based on them you can include/exclude certain components :)

Comment: Also - there's no specific point where any of us can tell you when to break it into two components, it's mainly up to you. If it starts to get too messy for you using one, and if as you said desktop is so simple yet mobile is so complex they definitely sound like a different components to me. I'd suggest in react to break everything into as smaller components as you possibly could :)